# How to open *.aux file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

My university desires to switch from using ArcGIS to using QGIS and therefore I have to figure out whether the exercises that are used in lectures can be performed using QGIS.

I have an .AUX file that can be used in ArcGIS. When I want to open this file in QGIS, the file shows up in the layers list but no image is drawn on the canvas. Also, there is no attribute table. In ArcGIS, there is an image drawn and there is an attribute table. What could cause these differences and how to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Can you show us the source data?

Comment: I created a picture of the metadata: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/metadatascanmap.png/

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are talking about the .aux files which belongs to a raster file.

The .aux file stores additional information. The image is stored in a raster file (e.g. .tif .img). You have to open the raster file in QGIS, not the .aux file.

As described in the [ArcGIS help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Auxiliary_files/009t00000027000000/) an auxiliary file can store the following:

- Color map
- Statistics, histogram, or table
- Pointer to the pyramid file
- Coordinate system Transformation
- Projection information