# How to open a "Raster Dataset" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I want to open a "Raster Dataset" in QGIS. In ArcMAP I can just add it like shown in the Screenshot (only the raster shows up).

[image: Screenshot 1]

If I am trying to do this in QGIS. However there I don't see the raster files itself. I find three files (`.ovr`, `.aux`, and `.ovr.aux.xml`) and a folder (with `.adf` files inside it). How can I open the raster?
[image]

A similar question was already asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62857/how-to-open-aux-file-in-qgis) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/how-can-i-load-adf-files-to-quantum-gis), but never really answered.

Comment: .adf is vector (E$RI coverage)? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/how-can-i-load-adf-files-to-quantum-gis

Comment: In the ArcCatalog these three files are just shown as one "File System Raster"

Comment: Are you sure the raster data you are hoping to use is a raster?  If you are using an ESRI grid, or TIN, they are not gdal supported rasters, so they will never show as available raster formats in QGIS.

Comment: Yes I am fairly sure. Because I can also use them as raster directly in GDAL and that works (by just setting the path to it).

Comment: I agree with Ryan as far as i know `.ovr` files are simply external pyramid files (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000026000000.htm). They are **not** the raster layer source

Comment: You guys are right. `.ovr` are the pyramids of the raster. Meanwhile I found that `.adf` files are the raster files. The problem was also discussed here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/how-can-i-load-adf-files-to-quantum-gis

Comment: @Mapperz *.adf can be either [raster (ESRI grid)](http://home.gdal.org/projects/aigrid/aigrid_format.html) or [vector (ESRI coverage)](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_avcbin.html).

Comment: @RyanGarnett - ESRI grids are definitely supported by GDAL - http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AIG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"In QGIS you can simply open the file `w001001.adf` using the normal ‘add raster layer’ dialogue. You may have to change the symbology in the raster layer properties (double click on the just imported layer in the Layers panel), try e.g., the pseudocolor Color map."
- found [here](http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/esri-rasters-in-grass-or-qgis/)