# How to load, in QGIS, raster datasets originally mosaicked in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I have used ArcGIS for years in an academic context but have very recently started using QGIS in earnest as my ArcGIS license is expired and I want to experience a new set of soul rending frustrations. I have a large catalog of DEM rasters from the US National Elevation Dataset (in ArcGRID and/or Gridfloat format) that have been mosaicked with ArcGIS. I do not know how to give more data on them, as I cannot access them in ArcCatalog and they do not show up in QGIS' Browser (at least as files I'm used to seeing or whose structure I can understand).

When I "Add Raster Data" in QGIS and open the file browse (Windows) dialog (with the "`...`" button), navigate to my geodatabase, I am given the option to choose from a number of file types, none of which seem to be the actual raster/mosaic I'm looking for (like I would see in ArcCatalog). When I click the file type dropdown, I can narrow down the selection, but none of the individual files in the geodatabase folder are of any of those types.

I have `ATX(.atx) FREELIST(.freelist) GDBINDEXES(.gdbindex) GDBTABLE(.gdbtable) GDBTABLX(.gdbtablx) LOCK(.sr.lock) SPX(.spx) SUBFILE(.subfile) SUBFILX(.subfilx)`, but none of these seem to be the actual data I am looking for. Adding any of these filetypes throws an INVALID LAYER error (`Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset G:[filepath] not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid...`)

How do I load a raster of this type into QGIS?

[THIS LINK](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74037/how-to-open-a-raster-dataset-in-qgis) seems to address the same question, but I don't seem to have any .adf files either (at least not with my *mosaicked* datasets.

I am using QGIS 3.6.2-Noosa on Windows 10

Comment: Only ArcGIS can access file geodatabase rasters.

Comment: Are you certain? From the link I referenced above, it seems to me that may not be accurate??? But perhaps I misunderstand the comment "ESRI grids are definitely supported by GDAL"

Comment: Arc/Info Grid format is ***completely*** different from geodatabase raster.  Neither the Esri FileGDB driver nor the open one supports raster.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS now supports import from ESRI Geodatabases by dragging them from the file catalog window into the QGIS project.